# User with 1 reputation is able to comment everywhere

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

According to the [Comment privileges](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) page, only after gaining 50 reputation can a user comment everywhere(on posts by other users).

> **Comment Everywhere**
>   Privilege Type: Communication Privilege
>   Awarded At: 50 Reputation

It is known that a user with even 1 reputation can comment on their own posts but cannot do so on posts by other users but seeing this [particular comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/is-dracule-mihawk-really-the-strongest-swordsman/5767#comment8803_5765) has raised issues on this feature. How can [a user](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/3679/user3679) with just 1 reputation comment on a question which was not posted by them? It mostly seems like a bug unless there was a change in the *Communication Privilege* feature.

FYR, this is that comment(in case it gets deleted later).

> Mihawk is not scared of him. They are friends. –  user3679 yesterday

Comment: If you think about it, there is this said bug that if you get the **plus 100** points bonus when you are trusted in another site. Then if your points in that another site is **revoked**, you still has the bonus 100 points **BUT** others see it as just 1 (if you don't have any other points aside from the bonus ) you still have the privilege as a 100 point user and you would be shown with 1 reputation. has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), and no, the user doesn't have the ability to comment everywhere yet.

♦ moderators have the ability to convert answers to comments. It happens fairly frequently here that new users who don't understand our policies will post answers which do not answer the question. When these answers are flagged as "Not an Answer" or if a moderator sees them before they're flagged, they'll delete them, but if the post makes sense as a comment the moderators will sometimes choose to convert it. That's what happened here, and as far as I know the only way that a <50 rep user can comment in places other than their own questions/answers and answers to their questions.

Here's a screenshot of what the deleted answer looks like for someone with the [moderator tools privilege](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (currently at 2k rep):

[image]

As a note, this user still can't post more comments on that post (as far as I know). If you try to respond to them, they can't talk back.

Comment: That's a correct and well explained answer.